# Drush make - errors unzipping and distinguishing mime times

Tags: drupal, drush

I've installed Drush 5.8 on Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise, with all the options included except Remote Management.

Whenever I run `drush make` I get errors about it not being able to unzip a github archive file, and unable to determine mime type for a js file.  Here is my make file and the output.  I'm not sure what is wrong here, and would love any pointers you may have.

**Make file:**

```
; Drupal 7 core
core = 7.x
api = 2
projects[drupal][version] = 7

; Libraries
; --------

libraries[colorbox][download][type] = "get"
libraries[colorbox][download][url] = "https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/archive/1.4.8.zip"
libraries[colorbox][directory_name] = colorbox
libraries[colorbox][destination] = libraries

libraries[zepto][download][type] = "get"
libraries[zepto][download][url] = "http://zeptojs.com/zepto.min.js"
libraries[zepto][directory_name] = zepto
libraries[zepto][destination] = libraries
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\drush>drush make test.make testing
Could not locate drupal version 7, will try to download latest recommended or supported release.               [warning]

drupal-7.21 downloaded.                                                                                             [ok]

colorbox downloaded from https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/archive/1.4.8.zip.                                   [ok]

Unable to unzip C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1/make_tmp_1364915473_515af511066a2/1.4.8.zip.              [error]

zepto downloaded from http://zeptojs.com/zepto.min.js.                                                              [ok]

Unable to determine mime type for zepto.min.js.                                                                  [error]
```

Comment: If it helps, when I run drush make in verbose mode I see "'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it figured out after a lot of struggle.

Using Cygwin I was able to get a copy of unzip, which I put in the Program Files (x86)\Drush\GnuWin32\bin directory (which is in my PATH environment variable). This cleared up the errors listed about unzip.

As for the mime-type issue, I had to manually edit includes/drush.inc to add `'.js' => 'application/javascript'` to the $extension_mimetype array. See http://drupal.org/node/1825946 for the discussion that led me to this.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, however I still struggle with the "unzip" error. [I've detailed it](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/155504/drush-make-error-unable-to-unzip) over at drupal.stackexchange, maybe you could help me to solve that? It would be appreciated.